# Styling nested links with CSS properly?

Tags: css, nested, html-lists

I just can't get my head around why I can't get the below shown CSS/HTML combo to work properly.
The links appear with default styling (blue&underlined). Maybe I am just tired or have I missed out on something essential?

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="main">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul.main li a:link, ul.main li a:visited, ul.main li a:hover, ul.main li a:active {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Why not style anchor element itself i.e. `ul.main li a` - it seems to be missing from your list!

Comment: I didn't thought that adding `ul.main li a` would be necessary? Tried it and no change...

Comment: The `:visited` selector is no longer acted on by most browsers (due to a subtle security issue with it), so it's fairly pointless to specify it any more. You can therefore safely remove it from your code. (it's still considered as a valid selector, so this won't make any difference to your question, but I just thought I'd point it out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all your styles are the same, just try

```
ul.main a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: @Industrial, advise you to use FireBug and see actual styles that are being applied on your links. It can be as simple as that your CSS is not included in the page.

Comment: how is your css included? because this works for me. Which means there is either a problem with your `<link />` tag, there is a css error above that is devalidating your code, or there is a cache problem with the browser.

Comment: @VinarC/Industrial, I also recommend trying it in another browser, ideally a webkit browser so you can "inspect element" (that would be chrome or safari).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your solution worked great, but for some reason the CSS was cached by firefox...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any other styles that are affecting achors, following should suffice

```
ul.main li a, ul.main li a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```